# Vue 3 <router-view> got commented after build using history mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli, vuejs3

When I build my Vue project using hash router mode it works perfectly, but when I build it using history mode, it only shows the navbar and commented the `<router-view>`. I have also configured my apache settings for history mode.

**router.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <Navbar />
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";

export default {
  components: { Navbar },
};
</script>
```

I could replace the `<router-view>` on my app.vue with the Home view component directly, it would work. But that defeats the point of using vue router ovbiously. Help me please guys!

Also, here is the server config, I'm using apache and deploying it on a subdirectory called v2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /v2/
  RewriteRule ^v2/index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . v2/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're serving the app from a subdirectory *`/v2`*, you need to configure  [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) accordingly in *`vue.config.js`*.  Create that file in your project root if it doesn't exist.

Use a conditional `publicPath`, from the [Vue CLI docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) which will allow you to serve it properly in both development and production:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/v2/'
    : '/'
}
```

Setting `publicPath` changes the value of `process.env.BASE_URL` used in the router's `history` property.